# How to take the integral $\int\frac{dx}{\sin^3x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

There's

$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sin^3x}.$$

I tried to write it like

$$\int\frac{(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)}{\sin^3x}\,\mathrm dx,$$

and then made partial fractions from it, but it didn't help much, the answer is still incorrect.

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by sin, and use that identithe on the denominator.

Comment: The incorrect answer you have obtained is?

Comment: it is csc^3 which is do-able by integration by parts I think - look for integration of sec^3 by parts (for clues)

Comment: Write it as $$\int\frac{\sin x dx}{(1-\cos^2 x)\sin^2 x}$$

Comment: here is a good article on it's cousin sec https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed#Integration_by_parts

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

*Bioche's rules* lead to to make the substitution $u=\cos x$, $\;\mathrm d u=\sin x \,\mathrm d x$. You obtain
$$\int\frac{\mathrm d x}{\sin^3 x}=\int\frac{-\mathrm d u}{\sin^4 x}=\int\frac{-\mathrm d u}{(1-u^2)^2}.$$
There remains to compute the *partial fraction decomposition* of $\;\dfrac{-1}{(1-u^2)^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

write your integrand as $$\frac{1}{\sin(x)}+\frac{\cos(x)^2}{\sin(x)^3}$$ and the first as $$\sin(x)+\frac{\cos(x)^2}{\sin(x)}$$
now you can set $$t=\sin(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=u+\frac\pi2$ to get

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sin^3(x)}=\int\frac{du}{\cos^3(u)}=\int\sec^3(u)\ du$$

This is a [well known integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed).  One technique is to apply integration by parts:

$$\int\sec(u)\ du=\sec(u)\tan(u)+\int\sec(u)\ du-\int\sec^3(u)\ du\\=\sec(u)\tan(u)+\ln|\sec(u)+\tan(u)|-\int\sec^3(u)\ du$$

In general, $\int\sec^n(x)\ dx$ should be handled with integration by parts and reduction formulas for odd $n$ and Pythagorean identities for even $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{\sin^3x}dx 
& = \int \frac{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}{4t^3}dt 
\\& =\frac{1}{4}\int \:\frac{1}{t^3}+t+\frac{2}{t}dt
\\& = \color{red}{\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\cot ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+2\ln \left|\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|\right)+C}
\end{aligned}
$$
Solved by substitution $\color{blue}{t=\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$